# Redirect Output of IO.popen into a logfile

Tags: ruby, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I'm running the [PDFKit Gem](https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit) to generate pdfs with [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).

When running specs or generating PDFs on my project, wkhtmtopdf leaks its output to `stdout` / different logs, but I want to have all the output generated in a separate logfile pdfkit.log in my application.

The invocation of wkhtmltopdf is straightforward

```
result = IO.popen(invoke, "wb+") do |pdf|
  pdf.puts(@source.to_s) if @source.html?
  pdf.close_write
  pdf.gets(nil)
end
```

I tried, [according to the IO.popen > Kernel.spawn documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn), to reconfigure the `IO.popen` call to put all the output into a logfile (`:err => [:child, :out]` should merge `stderr` and `stdout`, and `:out=>[File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'pdfkit.log'), "w"]` should write to the logfile specified)

```
result = IO.popen(invoke, "wb+", :out=>[File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'pdfkit.log'), "w"], :err=>[:child, :out]) do |pdf|
  pdf.puts(@source.to_s) if @source.html?
  pdf.close_write
  pdf.gets(nil)
end
```

The overwrite of the method is in place, but unfortunately does not work as expected. I know the error is me misinterpreting the options of `IO.popen`, but I don't see how..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
in_io_pipe, out_io_pipe = IO.pipe
out = File.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'pdfkit.log'), 'w+')
pid = Process.spawn(cmd, :out => out, :in => in_io_pipe, :err => out)
Process.detach(pid)
out_io_pipe.puts("something")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$stdout.reopen("out.txt", "w")
$stderr.reopen("err.txt", "w")
```

Comment: This writes the files after the command has been executed. My intention is to have the log running along.